# Hide Submit Button if Form validation fails

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a form that is divided in three tabbed panels. I need to have a function that will show a button that will show panel two only if all required fields from panel 1 are full.

the form elements are like this...

```
    <p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-  invalid-required-field" id="billing_first_name_field">

    <label for="billing_first_name" class="">First Name <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>

    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" placeholder="" value="">

    </p>
```

So if the required input fields are not entered the submit button will not be displayed.

Thanks

Comment: http://thecodemine.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
I'm grabbing the first step container, then looping through it's scope of input fields and validating that they aren't blank.

I'm then returning true or false, and if false adding an "invalid" class to the offending input.

```
function validateStep(step) {
    var $step_paragraph = $('p.form-row-' + step),
        is_valid = true;
    $('input', $step_paragraph).each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            input_value = $this.val();
        if (input_value.length) {
            is_valid = true;
            $this.removeClass('invalid');
        } else {
            is_valid = false;
            $this.addClass('invalid');
        }
    }
    return is_valid;
}
```

Then instantiate it on the next button being pressed:

```
validateStep('first');
```

I only just now saw your last requirement of not seeing the submit button until all fields are filled out. I would advise against this because it makes code really really really annoying, and it's horrible from a user experience standpoint. I would suggest validating on submit ONLY.

But if that's how you must do it, here's how it'll happen. Also notice that I'm reusing the validateStep function.

```
$('p.form-row-first').on('keyup', 'input', function () {
     if (validateStep('first')) { //that means all fields have text
         $('submit-button-first').show(); // you will need to select your actual button
     } else { //that means not all fields have text
         $('submit-button-first').hide();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution you can clean up.  http://jsfiddle.net/nhaines888/QhRDK/
Check when the input box typing has stopped, then make sure if its filled out. If it is, show the button for panel 2. You can also use a regex if you need to make sure the input needs specific content, i.e. text only, numbers, etc.

```
<p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-   invalid-required-field" id="billing_first_name_field">

<label for="billing_first_name" class="">First Name <abbr class="required"  title="required">*</abbr></label>

<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" placeholder="" value="">
<button id="btn1">SHOW PANEL 2</button>
</p>

<p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required woocommerce-invalid woocommerce- invalid-required-field" id="billing_last_name_field">

<label for="billing_last_name" class="">Last Name <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>

<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name" placeholder="" value="">
<button id="btn2">SHOW PANEL 3</button>
</p>

<script>
var timeoutReference;
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#billing_last_name_field").hide();
$("#btn1").hide();
$("#btn2").hide();

$('input#billing_first_name').keypress(function() {
    var _this = $(this); // copy of this object for further usage

    if (timeoutReference) clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
    timeoutReference = setTimeout(function() {
        if(_this.val() != "") {
            $("#btn1").show();
        }
    }, 400);
});

$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
    $("#billing_last_name_field").show();        
});

});
</script>
```